# Installation of pygalmesh in anaconda

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I wanted to install a python package “pygalmesh”. I tried the procedure suggested in following link: Pygalmesh :: Anaconda.org. However, it is taking very long time more than 2 hours making repeated trails.

How to resolve it? I posted a message on anaconda communities as well. But there was no response.

Comment: You should add the actual link as a link, instead of just text `Pygalmesh :: Anaconda.org`.

Comment: Are you trying this in `base` or in a fresh conda env? Try in a fresh conda env if you havn't done so

Comment: Thanks James for editing. The link is https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pygalmesh.  I am trying to install in conda env using conda power shell in navigator.